# scatter plots in pandas gives values error 'c' argument must be a color, a sequence of colors, or a sequence of numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing this script to create a color-mapped plot from the attached data frame.

here is the code

```
biaxial_plot_ICOS_PD1 = sorted_df.plot.scatter(x="ICOS - costimulator:Cyc_14_ch_4"
                                               , y="PD-1 - checkpoint:Cyc_12_ch_4"
                                               , c="ClusterName", colormap='viridis', s=50)
```

But I get this error

```
ValueError: 'c' argument must be a color, a sequence of colors, or a sequence of numbers, not ['CD4+ T cells' 'CD4+ T cells' 'CD4+ T cells' ... 'CD4+ T cells CD45RO+' 'CD4+ T cells CD45RO+' 'CD4+ T cells GATA3+']
```

sorted_df:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you provide a column label to the `c` parameter, the values of that column should be valid numbers to be mapped to colors according to the colormap provided. From the [docs of `DataFrame.plot.scatter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html)

> **c : str, int or array-like, optional**
>
> The color of each point. Possible values are:
>
> - A single color string referred to by name, RGB or RGBA code, for instance ‘red’ or ‘#a98d19’.
> - A sequence of color strings referred to by name, RGB or RGBA code, which will be used for each point’s color recursively. For instance [‘green’,’yellow’] all points will be filled in green or yellow, alternatively.
> - A column name or position **whose values will be used to color the marker points according to a colormap**.

The `c` parameter is not directly interpreted as "color by this column". If you want something like that use `seaborn`.

In your case, it seems that you want to color based on `ClusterName`, so you can use `groupby` + `ngroup`, so that each `ClusterName` is mapped to a distinct integer, meaning to a different color.

This should work

```
cluster_colors = sorted_df.groupby('ClusterName').ngroup()
biaxial_plot_ICOS_PD1 = sorted_df.plot.scatter(x="ICOS - costimulator:Cyc_14_ch_4", 
                                               y="PD-1 - checkpoint:Cyc_12_ch_4",
                                               c=cluster_colors, colormap='viridis', s=50)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried seaborn and it worked:)